# Add image and value to a panel?

Tags: c#, image, panel

I was able to add image to my panel with the following code,
But now my problem is I need to retrieve some information from the image etc(key value)

Is that possible to add in a value to every image?

```
foreach (System.Drawing.Image img in imagelist) {
    PictureBox imagePicBox = new PictureBox();
    imagePicBox.Name = "image" + imagePanel.Controls.Count.ToString();                   
    imagePicBox.Image = img;              
    imagePicBox.Size = imagePicBox.Image.Size;
    imagePicBox.BackColor = Color.Black;
    imagePicBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    imagePicBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    imagePanel.Controls.Add(imagePicBox); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.tag(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the System.Drawing.Image to add whatever data you want. this is what it's there for.